# About the existence of a certain form

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be compact and oriented manifolds, with empty boundary. Let $n=\dim(N)<m=dim(M)$ and let $i:N\rightarrow M$ be an embedding. I am asked to prove that there exists some $\eta\in\Omega^{m-n}(M)$ such that for any $\omega\in\Omega^{n}(M)$ such that $d\omega=0$ one has that $\int_{N}i^{\ast}(\omega)=\int_{M}\omega\wedge\eta$.

Can somebody help me ? Or give any hints please ?
Thank you

Comment: you are right... i edited already. thanks

Comment: Do you know about Poincaré duality?

Comment: I would say "yes", but not deeply.

Comment: I recognize that the setting seems suitable to apply Poincaré Duality, but how ? Any hint/suggestion ? Thank you :)

Comment: One version of the Poincaré duality theorem states that the map from $H^n_{\text{dR}}(M)\times H^{m-n}_{\text{dR}}(M)$ to $\mathbb R$ given by $([\omega],[\eta])\mapsto \int_M\omega\wedge\eta$ is a [nondegenerate pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing).

Comment: So that means that there is an isomorphism between $H^{m-n}(M)$ and $(H^{n}(M))^{\ast}$ given by $\Phi(\beta)(\alpha)=\int_{M}\alpha\wedge\beta$. Thus, considering $F\in (H^{n}(M))^{\ast}$ given by $F(\alpha)=\int_{M}\alpha$, in particular there is $\eta\in H^{m-n}(M)$ such that $\Phi(\eta)(\omega)=F(\omega)$, and we can conclude the result. Is this line of reasoning correct ? Thank you so much for the hint by the way :)

Comment: Not quite. If $\alpha$ is an $n$-form (or cohomology class), then $\int_M\alpha$ doesn't make sense, because $M$ is an $m$-manifold.

Comment: Sure, it was a typo. I meant $F(\alpha)=\int_{N}i^{\ast}(\alpha)$. Does this make sense now or am I missing something ? (I'm sorry if I am being too persistent, but I am really tired...)

Comment: Looks good to me.